# Flutter / GraphQL - Mutation with custom type as parameter

Tags: dart, flutter, graphql

I'm new to flutter and graphQL and currently I'm integrating mutations into my app. So, I have the server side using some custom types defined in the schema, but I don't know how to specify them on the flutter side. Let's see some code:

```
input DiaryGroupPermission {
  groupId: Int!
  permission: Int!
}

input DiaryInsideCommunity {
  communityId: Int!
  permissions: [DiaryGroupPermission]!
}

createDiary(community: DiaryInsideCommunity, description: String, title: String!): Diary
```

But on the client I don't know how to specify the DiaryInsideCommunity inside the mutation.
I've tried something like this:

```
String createDiary = """
  mutation CreateDiary(\$title: String!, \$description: String!, \$community: DiaryInsideCommunity) {
    createDiary(
    title: \$title,
    description: \$description,
    community: \$community
  ) {
    id
  }
)}""".replaceAll('\n', ' ');
```

And passing my runMutation as follows:

```
runMutation({
            "title": _generalPage.title(),
            "description": _generalPage.description(),
            "community": {
              "communityId": 1,
              "permissions": _permissionPage.selectedGroups().map((group) {
                return {
                  "groupId": group.id,
                  "permission": 1,
                };
              }).toList(),
            }
          });
```

Any idea? Can't find anything on google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Love to see the community that is created around the graphql_flutter library.

```
class DiaryGroupPermission {
  int groupId;
  int permission;

  DiaryGroupPermission.fromJson(Map json)
      : groupId = json['groupId'],
        permission = json['permission'];
}

class DiaryInsideCommunity {
  int communityId;
  List<DiaryGroupPermission> permissions;

  DiaryInsideCommunity.fromJson(Map json)
      : communityId = json['communityId'],
        permissions = json['permissions']
            .map<DiaryGroupPermission>((Map permisionJson) =>
                DiaryGroupPermission.fromJson(permisionJson))
            .toList();
}

class Diary {
  String body;

  Diary(dynamic value) : body = value.toString();
}

typedef Diary createDiaryFunction(
    DiaryInsideCommunity community, String description, String title);

DiaryInsideCommunity community = DiaryInsideCommunity.fromJson({
  'communityId': 1,
  'permissions': [
    {'groupId': 1, 'permission': 1}
  ]
});

Diary mutation(DiaryInsideCommunity community,
        {String description, @required String title}) =>
    Diary(community.permissions[0].groupId);

Diary mutationResult = mutation(community, description: "a", title: "b");
```

I implemented the types that you wanted to in dart and created a mockup mutation function to show you how to call it.

There is no easier way to do types in dart.

Cheers from the creator of this library,

Eus

Comment: Does it really work? Shouldn't `DiaryInsideCommunity` be defined inside `gql` on the client?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using [graphql_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/graphql_flutter),
You may specify it in variables 
an example is say you have this definitions for a mutation

```
 type Mutation {
 createMeterReading(
  createMeterReadingInput: CreateMeterReadingInput
 ): MeterReading }
```

your input type definition

```
     input CreateMeterReadingInput {
           reading: Float
           companyId: Int
           companyStaffId: Int
           customerId: Int
           readingDataType: String
           latitude: Float
           longitude: Float
           masterMeterId: Int
           analogMeterId: Int
           type: String
           editedStatus: String
           base64Image: String
           readingTime: String
     }
```

In flutter have

```
 final response = await client.value.mutate(MutationOptions(
  variables: {
    'createMeterReadingInput': {
      'reading': double.parse(_meterReadingController.text),
      'companyStaffId': _decodedToken["companyStaffId"],
      'analogMeterId': waterMeter["analogMeterId"],
      'type': "actual",
      'base64Image': getBase64(),
      'readingTime': timeNow,
      'latitude': widget?.currentPosition?.latitude,
      'longitude': widget?.currentPosition?.longitude
    }
  },
  documentNode: gql(r"""
mutation createMeterReading($createMeterReadingInput:CreateMeterReadingInput  ) {
  createMeterReading(createMeterReadingInput: $createMeterReadingInput) {
 meterReadingId
reading
companyId
companyStaffId
imageUrl
editedStatus
companyStaff{
  firstName
}
}
}


"""),
));
```

Comment: Have you tried this with dgraph/slash graphQL? Mutations there are not working for me